# kubernetes health check look for string

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a container that has a ping endpoint (returns pong) and I want to probe the ping endpoint and see if I get a pong back. If it was just to check 200 , I could have added a liveliness check in my pod like this ->

```
livenessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 2
  periodSeconds: 5
  httpGet:
    path: /ping
    port: 9876
```

How do I modify this to check  to see if I get a `pong` response back?

Comment: Http probe check the status and header response, it does not check the response body. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request

Comment: @SureshVishnoi it does not check response headers, see the doc and my answer. But you can set request headers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the HTTP probe only checks the status code of the response, you need to use the exec probe to run a command on the container. Something like this, which requires `curl` being installed on the container:

```
livenessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 2
  periodSeconds: 5
  exec:
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - curl -s http://localhost:9876/ping | grep pong
```

Answer (score 1):

httpGet livenessProbe and readinessProbe only care about **http response code**

> Any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400 indicates success. Any other code indicates failure.

Better to change your *pong* message to set the appropriate http status code on the response.